# change content if update is made in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase with react to get some posts.
I would like to update posts on the screen in realtime if anything changes on it using react.

I print this posts like this:

```
  return (
    <>
      {posts.map((post, index) => {

//firebase to check updates
var postref = firebase.database().ref('/posts/' + post.key).orderByKey();
postref.on("value", function(snap) {
    var changedPost = snap.val();
    console.log("The updated post title is " + changedPost.titulo);
});

        return <Post key={post.key} id={post.key} ref={ref} img={post.img} titulo={post.titulo} />

      })}
    </>
  )
}
```

in the middle I have firebase, to check if any update has been made, for example if someone edited the title. It is working, console.log the title if it changes.

The problem is, how can I update this edited title to the user in realtime using react? Should I create a state? array of states for each post? what can I do to update post.titulo if any changes occurs?

thanks

Comment: Have you check `includeMetadataChanges`, https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: @HagaiHarari thanks for your answer. I'm using firebase and it is working nice to get realtime updates, if someone update a post, the console.log will print the new title. I just need to know how to show this to user, update the post in the screen with the new title.

Answer (score 1):

For making react component re-render, you need either change state or props to make it draw UI again with a new context. I don't sure what exactly `posts` is and how do you fetch it (maybe using custom hook there is the best practice...), but adding a possible way to do it

---

```
 const [ uiPosts, setUIposts ] = useState({})

 {posts.map((post, index) => 
    setUIposts({...uiPosts, [post.key]: ...post})
    var postref = firebase.database().ref('/posts/' + post.key).orderByKey();
  postref.on("value", function(snap) {
    setUIposts({...uiPosts, [post.key]: ...post})
});

    return <Post  titulo={uiPosts[post.key].titulo} />

  })}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll try!